set style of e.currentTarget on click without using useState hook?
Is it possible in React Native to set the style of a button by using e.currentTarget method? Since there is a style object inside the currentTarget object. I mean:
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => e.currentTarget.style.color="red"} >  // ERROR comes


In React Native, TochableOpacity component doesn't work exactly like the native elements in the web environment. Therefore you can't directly set styles using e.currentTarget.style as you might in a web-based react application.

How about Pressable or other components?

@JeremyFc that‘s not how react-native work. Pass a style prop and trigger a rerender.

Set the color pop with useState and pass it to the component style prop.
You should avoid direct manipulation.
Why you don’t want use useState ?
const [touchableColor, setTouchableColor] = useState("blue")

<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: touchableColor}} onPress={() => setTouchableColor("red")} >  // ERROR comes


